# Ruby regex extract content between 2 tags

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string like this:

`str = "TO ALL >>>
[info][title] Daily report ({{today}})[/title]
■ Today schedule
{{task-list}}
- {{task}}
{{/task-list}}
■ Actual
{{task-list}}
- {{actual}}
{{/task-list}}
■ Reason cannot complete work
{{problems}}
■ Next day plan
{{next_day_plan}}
[/info]"`

I want to use regex to extract all content between 2 tags {{task-list}} and {{/task-list}}. I use this regex:

`str.scan /(?<=({{task-list}}))(\D|\d)+?(?=({{\/task-list}}))/`

But result don't extract the whole content between 2 tags but the last character:
`[["{{task-list}}", "\n", "{{/task-list}}"], ["{{task-list}}", "\n", "{{/task-list}}"]]`

Wat did I miss ?

Comment: Wrap `(\D|\d)+?` in another capturing group. Also you want to replace it with `[\d\D]*?`.

Comment: Then I can't reproduce http://rubular.com/r/EDqlk93XbU

Comment: @revo That's exactly what I want, Thank you very much!!

Comment: @elkun49 Why use workarounds like `((?:\d|\D)*?)` or `[\d\D]*?` when a `.` with `m` modifier will do the job in a "built-in" way? Use `str.scan(/{{task-list}}(.*?){{\/task-list}}/m)`